# Make checkstyle require the Java 7 Diamond operator

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to make checkstyle require java 7 formatting of the diamond operator? I want to ensure my codebase consistently uses the new Java 7 style, i.e.:

```
List<String> items = new LinkedList<>();
```

instead of the older:

```
List<String> items = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a rule for that but as final solution you could always [write your own rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).

Comment: Your ide might be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/bugs/645/).

One of the users is complaining about a bug in the diamond operator grammar:

```
  List list = new ArrayList<>();
  throws an error:unexpected token: >
```

This bug report was closed thanks to a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/patches/213/) that adds support for Java 7.

According to the page, one of the features added was:

```
4) Diamond Generics: In presence of a diamond, the AST looks like:

+--TYPE_ARGUMENTS
|
+--GENERIC_START
+--GENERIC_END
```

[Download](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/patches/_discuss/thread/7c41e29a/cf9b/attachment/Java7Support.patch) link for the patch.

Comment: I did come across that. The patch is 6 months old. Are you saying to get this feature you have to download the source, apply the patch and compile your own version of checkstyle?

Comment: The bug report link is dead. Any idea whether this is solved meanwhile?